# How to build setup file in Visual Studio with obfuscated assembly?

Tags: c#, obfuscation, crypto-obfuscator

I am obfuscating my assembly with crypto obfuscator, after obfuscating my assembly, I verify with the crypto-obfuscator program if the assembly has been obfuscated. When the assembly is obfuscated I copy it and a file with .pdb extension to bin/debug where my visual studio is pointing.

Assuming whatever is in my bin/debug folder is packaged into setup msi file. When I install the setup and check if the installed assembly is obfuscated, it is NOT.

I tried to look answers on stack overflow but I couldn't get my answer.

If you require more information. Please let me know.

Comment: Typically, Obfuscators act on the Release assembly not Debug ones.  You ought not be distributing Debug versions or PDBs

Comment: I tried both. Debug and Release, I still got un-obfuscated assembly.

Comment: Maybe your build system is replacing your obfuscated assembly with a new output if it is building your dependent projects when you build your installer output (e.g. default behavior in Visual Studio)?

Comment: my build system is using setup file from Obj/x86/Debug/Myapp.exe I also replaced my assembly there, still I got un-obfuscated assembly.

Comment: I was in my obj/x86/debug folder, I saw that when I build my setup, my build system is replacing my obfuscated assembly with new output and that is un-obfuscated assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I have found solution to this problem.
- I Deleted Primary output from     my visual studio 2010 (Setup)
  Project.
- I Added "Obfuscated" Assembly     in my setup instead.
- When I built the setup, the assembly came as       obfuscated when
  installed.

that was simple. Keep in mind Do not change the file name in any way in "Custom Actions" your program will not work.

When you choose Custom Action "Install" Select your assembly which you added in Application folder that is obfuscated assembly.